# W3 Total Cache and User Agent Groups

Tags: mobile, w3-total-cache, page-caching

We are using W3 Total Cache (Page Cache - Disk: Basic). This causes generation of same cache for desktop and mobile.

We need separate cache for mobile and desktop for which we tried to use User Agent Groups but it seems like either we have not configured it correctly or it is not working as expected.

Our configuration is as follows:
[image: for iphone and android devices]

[image: for other devices]

But still the generated cache remains same for both, following are the debug info for both desktop and mobile:

Desktop:

```
Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: https://www.w3-edge.com/products/

Page Caching using disk
Page cache debug info:
Engine:             disk
Cache key:          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Creation Time:      1478697928.000s
Header info:
Set-Cookie:          _wp_session=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; expires=Wed, 09-Nov-2016 13:55:27 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/
Content-Type:        text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By:        W3 Total Cache/0.9.5.1
Link:                <http://my-site.com/>; rel=shortlink

 Served from: my-site.com @ 2016-11-09 13:25:28 by W3 Total Cache
```

iPhone:

```
<!-- Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: https://www.w3-edge.com/products/

Page Caching using disk
Page cache debug info:
Engine:             disk
Cache key:          50e7360d67b0ae9ff4a13ced7367e6c5
Creation Time:      1478697928.000s
Header info:
Set-Cookie:          _wp_session=xxxxxxxxxxx; expires=Wed, 09-Nov-2016 13:55:27 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/
Content-Type:        text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By:        W3 Total Cache/0.9.5.1
Link:                <http://my-site.com:81/>; rel=shortlink

 Served from: my-site.com @ 2016-11-09 13:25:28 by W3 Total Cache -->
```

Generated datetime for both caches is the same which means there isn't any separate cache for mobile.

Can anybody help if I am not configuring it correctly or missing any other part?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?
I kinda have the same problem